# Parsing values from string into struct using match in Julia

Tags: parsing, regex, julia

## My goal

I am parsing from a string which contains `token:value` pairs into a type.

Example:

```
mutable struct Foo
    bar
    baz
    qux
end

function parse(str::AbstractString)::Foo
    f = Foo()

    bar_pattern = r"bar:(\w*)"
    baz_pattern = r"baz:(\d*)"
    qux_pattern = r"qux:(\w*)"

    f.bar = match(bar_pattern, s)[1]
    f.baz = match(baz_pattern, s)[1]
    f.qux = match(qux_pattern, s)[1]

    return d
end
```

## Problem

**This works** but only if the patterns are actually present. When `match` can't find the pattern, it returns `nothing`, which of course can't be indexed `[1]` or accessed with `captures`. The result is an error.

*I want the fields of the returned struct to either get the matched result (the "capture") directly, or remain empty or set to `nothing`, should the match be unable to find the pattern.*

**I could do** something like this:

```
function safeparse(str::AbstractString)::Foo
    f = Foo()

    bar_pattern = r"bar:(\w*)"
    baz_pattern = r"baz:(\d*)"
    qux_pattern = r"qux:(\w*)"

    if !isnothing(match(bar_pattern, s))
        f.bar = match(bar_pattern, s)[1]
    end

    if !isnothing(match(baz_pattern, s))
        f.baz = match(baz_pattern, s)[1]
    end

    if !isnothing(match(qux_pattern, s))
        f.qux = match(qux_pattern, s)[1]
    end

    return f
end
```

But that approach seems ugly and becomes verbose very quick if more/new patterns are introduced.

## Question

Is there a nicer but readable way to achieve this?

*Preferably* without combining/changing the regex patterns or *too* much regex magic, however I am
open to that route too if it is the only nice (less verbose) way. I am of course also open to general tips.

To keep things simple, just assume that the patterns my example is looking for only appear 0 or 1 times. *However* if the only way to make this nicer involves writing another function like `safematch` which does the check for nothing and returns the captured value or nothing, I would want *that* to also work with multiple matches somehow and stay a bit more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing I can think of is to use `eachmatch` -- when there is no match at all, it returns an empty iterator:

```
julia> collect(eachmatch(r"(bar:(\w*))", "bla bar:werfsd 1223 bar:skdf"))
2-element Array{RegexMatch,1}:
 RegexMatch("bar:werfsd", 1="bar:werfsd", 2="werfsd")
 RegexMatch("bar:skdf", 1="bar:skdf", 2="skdf")

julia> collect(eachmatch(r"(bar:(\w*))", "bla "))
RegexMatch[]
```

Then you can simply combine those into a dictionary, for example:

```
julia> Dict(re => [m[1] for m in eachmatch(re, s)] for re in patterns)
Dict{Regex,Array{T,1} where T} with 3 entries:
  r"qux:(\w*)" => Union{Nothing, SubString{String}}[]
  r"baz:(\d*)" => SubString{String}["33"]
  r"bar:(\w*)" => SubString{String}["werfsd", "skdf"]
```

Without further information about how you want to organize your data structure when more then one value occurs, I can't really say more.  Perhaps you can make use of [`merge`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.merge).

Give types to struct fields, and don't use mutable structs unless necessary.  Without knowing more, I suggest

```
struct Foo
    bar::Union{String, Nothing}
    baz::Union{String, Nothing}
    qux::Union{String, Nothing}
end
function Foo(;bar=nothing, baz=nothing, qux=nothing) 
    return Foo(convert(Union{String, Nothing}, bar),
               convert(Union{String, Nothing}, baz),
               convert(Union{String, Nothing}, qux))
end
```

which also takes care of converting the `SubString` from the regex match, in case this is relevant.